# Find maximum by day in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, max

In my application I have a model called Pdata which contains (amongst others) the columns pdc (integer) and timestamp. pdc is a measurement value that is done every 5 minutes.

**My question is:
What is the best way to get the maximum pdc for each day?**

The result should be a list of the maximum pdc value and the timestamp (or Pdata.id).

Thanks a lot, Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of `maximum` and `group`. You need to extract the date part of the timestamp and group on it. The syntax for extracting the date can vary depending on the database, but give this a try:

```
Pdata.group("DATE(timestamp)").maximum(:pdc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Pdata.where(timestamp: (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)).order(timestamp: :desc)
```